# Arithmetic overflow error When sorting by [TimeStamp] (column name)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting the error:

`Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type smalldatetime`

Please note that I've already searched this topic, but my bug is unique because it is caused by the `ORDER BY` clause. the problematic line(s) is
`WHEN 'TimeStamp' THEN [MyTable].[TimeStamp]`.

when I comment those `TimeStamp`, the query executed successfully, but I still need a solution for sorting my `TimeStamp` column (renaming the column is not possible).

This is my query:

```
SELECT
    Id,
    [TimeStamp],
    StatusCode
FROM 
    (
    SELECT 
        TOP (@EndRecord) ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
        (       
        ORDER BY
            CASE @SortDirection
                WHEN 'Desc' THEN
                    CASE @SortColumn                        
                        WHEN 'Id' THEN [MyTable].[Id]
                        WHEN 'TimeStamp' THEN [MyTable].[TimeStamp]
                        WHEN 'StatusCode' THEN [MyTable].[StatusCode]

                        ELSE [MyTable].[TimeStamp]
                    END
            END DESC,
            CASE @SortDirection
                WHEN 'Asc' THEN
                    CASE @SortColumn                        
                        WHEN 'Id' THEN [MyTable].[Id]
                        WHEN 'TimeStamp' THEN [MyTable].[TimeStamp]                     
                        WHEN 'StatusCode' THEN [MyTable].[StatusCode]                       

                        ELSE [MyTable].[TimeStamp]
                    END             
            END ASC                 
        ) AS 'Row',
        [MyTable].[Id] AS 'Id',
        [MyTable].[TimeStamp] AS 'TimeStamp',
        [MyTable].[StatusCode] AS 'StatusCode'
    FROM  
        [MyTable]
    WHERE 
        (@Filter_Id is null or [MyTable].[Id] = @Filter_Id) AND     
        (@Filter_StatusCode is null or [MyTable].[StatusCode] = @Filter_StatusCode) AND
        (@Filter_FromTimeStamp IS NULL OR [MyTable].[TimeStamp] >= @Filter_FromTimeStamp) AND
        (@Filter_TillTimeStamp IS NULL OR [MyTable].[TimeStamp] <= @Filter_TillTimeStamp)
    ) AS t1
WHERE 
    Row >=@StartRecord AND 
    Row <= @EndRecord
```

Comment: @gcaton My Column name is 'TimeStamp'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `CASE` *expression* has to return a value of a particular *type*. All `THEN` clauses have to agree as to the type or allow the [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql) rules to determine the overall type and apply conversions.

Since you probably don't want to e.g. convert everything to strings and perform ordering operations based on the *textual* sorting rules, you need to split out your `CASE` expressions so that you're not forcing any conversions between types.

E.g.

```
    ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN @SortDirection='Desc' and @SortColumn = 'Id'                        
             THEN [MyTable].[Id]
        END DESC,
        CASE WHEN @SortDirection='Desc' and @SortColumn = 'TimeStamp'                        
             THEN [MyTable].[TimeStamp]
        END DESC,
        CASE WHEN @SortDirection='Desc' and @SortColumn='StatusCode'
             THEN [MyTable].[StatusCode]
        END DESC,
        CASE WHEN @SortDirection='Desc' and @SortColumn not in ('Id','TimeStamp','StatusCode')
            THEN [MyTable].[TimeStamp]
        END DESC,
```

And similarly for your ascending sorts.